# how to show image when loading ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

i want to show image when ajax is loading the page then hide it again

 then i try this code but the image don't show first all done at the same time ( the php page take about 3 seconds to load ) so when i remove the comment from the line `$("img").css("display","none");` the image never appear

 here the full code

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#al").click(function(){
        $("img").css("display","inline");
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax load.php",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        document.getElementById("showhere").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
//  $("img").css("display","none");
    });
});
```

Comment: i put at css that img is display:none

Comment: So, are you seeing any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: no there are no error

Comment: Also, you have a line that looks like `xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax load.php",false);`.  The "ajax load.php" looks like an invalid get request.  Could be something to do with that.

Comment: but i want first the image appear then the page loading then the image hide
but now all happen at the same time

Comment: Obviously is doesn't appear. As soon as the async request goes out you already remove it. The code will not stop while getting the data.

Comment: check your responseText!

Comment: Not necessarily, it's a SYNCHRONOUS xmlhttp request, so as the OP posted, it should wait for a response first, then remove the image.

Comment: the page is loading already

Comment: so what is the solution

Comment: I think I figured it out.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use jquery ajax $.get function (I take it the php filename is ajax_load.php?):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#al").click(function(){
        $("img").css("display","inline");
        $.get("ajax_load.php","",function(data) {
            document.getElementById("showhere").innerHTML = data;
            $("img").css("display","none");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS

```css
#Loading {
    background:url(images/abc.gif) no-repeat center center;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

Use HTML

```
<div id="Loading" class="dvLoading">
</div>
```

And thn at before Ajax call show the div and after Ajax call hide the div

```
$('.dvLoading').show(); 
$('.dvLoading').hide();
```

Comment: abc.gif is the loader image

Answer (score 2):

As you are already using jQuery, thus use [**.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/), and hide image on its callback method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#al").click(function () {
        $("img").css("display", "inline");
        $("#showhere").load("ajaxload.php", function () {
            $("img").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You already use jQuery so you can leverage the standard ajax facility which takes many options among which a `success` and `error` function: [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

In these two functions you should put

```
$("img").css("display","none");
```

While the `display:inline` goes one line above the call to send the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap everything after the display inline in a setTimeout function with a 2-5 ms delay:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#al").click(function(){
        $("img").css("display","inline");
        setTimeout(function() {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax load.php",false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            document.getElementById("showhere").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            $("img").css("display","none");
        }, 2);
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what the main problem is, but I know that with CSS, sometimes changing properties acts like an asynchronous action.  Speculating, I think you have a race condition in which the css changes compete with the request and they end up happening all at the same time.  This hack essentially tells the request to wait a few milliseconds which allows the css change to append in the asynchronous queue before the request.